# My Titanium Post Works, how do I display in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, titanium-mobile

Hi im trying to send data from my titanium app to my Apache Web Service. The snippet of titanium code works as the output to the console is success. Now what im trying to do is when the post is sent, display the contents of the post on the web service page. Is my doPost correct?

**Titanium Snippet**

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

var params = {
    "places" : {
        Country : textCountry.getValue(),
        Capital : textCapital.getValue()
    }
};

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({});

// function to deal with errors
xhr.onerror = function() {
    Ti.API.info('error, HTTP status = ' + this.status);
    alert('Error Sending Data');
};

// function to deal with response
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log('success, HTTP status = ' + this.status);
};

xhr.open("POST", 'http://130.206.127.43:8080/Test');

//set enconding
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));

});
```

**Java Servlet/Apache Tomcat Snippet**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException
{

    String jsonData = request.getParameter("json");
    response.setContentType("applicaiton/json");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    out.println(jsonData);
    out.close();
}
```

**18/02/205**

```
// function to deal with response
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log('success, HTTP status = ' + this.status);
    Ti.API.info('json' + this.responseText);
};

[INFO] :   success, HTTP status = 200
[INFO] :   json = null
```

Comment: Your java code doesn't even compile, getPsrameter

Comment: Also at no point in your js code do you set a parameter on the request called 'json'

Comment: getPsrameter was a type error (edited), and that's what im trying to get help with

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting to be returned data wise, but your Servlet function is a VOID return type so it won't return data.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the xhr.onload and look at the variables that are present before your write your log.

You are looking for the this.responseText, which will have the response from your call to the Java servlet.  I mainly use WCF and C# and if I don't setup the WCF service specifically to clean-up the output, it will add the function name to the response.

Generally, my onload looks like this.

```
xhr.onload = function(){    
    var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.log(result);
}
```

*** Look closer at your Java Servlet return type.  It is a VOID return type so no data will be returned to the http call. ***

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient

Comment: thanks for your positive reply, i have edited my question above, i am getting null for xhr.send() im not too sure why